# Save history with model on callback ModelCheckpoint

Tags: keras, callback, history

I use keras callback ModelCheckpoint to save my best train model. It is possible to save the corresponding history in same way for plotting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [CSVLogger](https://keras.io/callbacks/#csvlogger) callback from keras along with your ModelCheckpoint in the list of callbacks.

```
history = model.fit(X,y, epochs=100, callbacks=[keras.callbacks.CSVLogger('history.csv')])
```

This will dump all metrics information at each epoch to CSV file which you can use for plotting.
Also, *model.fit* returns keras History object which can further be used for [visualization](https://keras.io/visualization/).

Comment: And to re-load it?